# Sum of geometric progression $z^{-m}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, z-transform

We know that the sum of the geometric progression of $z^{-n}$ where $n$ starts at zero and goes to infinity is $1/(1-z)$, but is there a way to show the sum when $n$ starts at $m$? I.e. what is

$$\sum_{n=m}^\infty \frac{1}{z^n}$$

Answer (score 5):

$$
  \sum_{k=m}^\infty z^{-k} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{-m - k} = z^{-m}\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{-k}
$$

Comment: Ok, so you treat z^-m like a constant and multiply the whole sequence by it. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{1-z}$ is the sum of $z^k$ (when $|z|<1$), NOT $z^{-k}$ (in this case the sum would be $\frac{z}{z-1}$ and $|z|$ would be greater than $1$).
However if $|z|<1$ we have that

$$
\sum_{k=m}^{+\infty}z^{k}=
\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}z^{k}-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}z^{k}=\frac{1}{1-z}-\frac{1-z^m}{1-z}
=\frac{z^m}{1-z}
$$

If you mean $z^{-k}$ changes only a few: as already said $|z|>1$ and you'd have just to turn $z$ into $\frac{1}{z}$ in the above formula:
$$
\sum_{k=m}^{+\infty}z^{-k}=\frac{\frac1{z^m}}{1-\frac1{z}}=\frac{1}{z^m-z^{m-1}}
$$